# col-md-6 não esta caindo no mobile

Tags: html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tenho uma `section` que no mobile invés de cair para baixo esta sobrepondo a div inteira.

[image: Como esta]

É para ficar assim, porém a imagem esta ficando por cima de tudo no mobile.

[image: Como é para ficar]

**HTML**

```
  <section class="second-section">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center box-orange">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="w-100" src="img/campos.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ml-5 ml-md-0 text-center">
      <h3>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem <div class="line"></div>
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, esse dolore. Ex voluptatibus ipsum, perferendis alias at necessitatibus minima, sequi facilis odio illum nostrum provident expedita eaque modi animi quasi.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.second-section{
.box-orange{
background-image:url('/img/fundo2.png');
height: 400px;
color: white;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-bottom: 10%;
img{
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: -10%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
h3{
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  .line{
    width: 80%;
    border: 3px solid #77D3C2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 33%;
    top: 100%;
  }
}

p{
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 0% 10%;
  }
 }
}
```

No inspecionar elemento não mostra o motivo dele estar por cima, esta pegando o mesmo do CSS

[image: Inspecionar elemento]

---

### Edit 1

Após colocar um `media rule` definindo a img para auto ela ficou assim.
[image: Edit 1]

No inspecionar elemento ele fica como `height:auto;`

Comment: Quando você diz “mobile”, você se refere a dispositivos que não são tablets correto?

Comment: Não to encontrando esse erro por nada :(

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS width: -728px

Comment: @Sam editei a pergunta com o inspecionar elemento, mas não parece ter nada de errado.

Comment: @Sam é SCSS, esqueci de mencionar.

Comment: Isso é porque a imagem está com altura fixa de 550px. Coloque no final do seu CSS uma @media rule: `@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
   .second-section img{
     height: auto;
   }
}
`

Comment: @Sam vê o edit.

Comment: Então. Aí vc ajusta as propriedades (altura, margens etc) como quiser no @media.

Comment: Mas tentei colocar um min-width:100%; no .box-orange, porém ele não mudou.

Answer (score -1):

Regras de grid do Bootstrap são as seguintes:

Extra small <576px: Col-1 ao Col-12,

Small 540px: Col-sm-1 ao Col-sm-12,

Medium ≥768px: Col-md-1 ao Col-md-12,

Large ≥992px: Col-lg-1 ao Col-lg-12,

Extra Large ≥1200px: Col-xl-1 ao col-xl-12,

No SCSS você pode usar da seguinte forma se for um mobile menor que 576px use dessa forma: `@extend .col-12;`.

Caso seja um mobile maior ou igual 576px pode usar dessa forma: `@extend .col-sm-12;`.

Isso segue sucessivamente até as demais visões, espero ter te ajudado e tirado suas dúvidas

Comment: Já havia visto estas regras, porém sem sucesso ao tentar aplica-las.

Comment: Me manda o código que você ta querendo aplicar por favor, para eu entender melhor sua dúvida.

Comment: Se for tratamento de imagem o Bootstrap tem o img-fluid essa class ela permite você redimensionar imagem proporcional pelo height que me lembre perfeitamente, ai não perde a qualidade.

Comment: Todo o código com o exemplo de como deve ficar esta na pergunta.

Comment: Já havia adicionado img-fluid, mas nada mudou

Comment: pega a class box-orange e coloca em uma div em volta do texto, e da um z-index: 999; na imagem e um margin-top:0; no box-orange e só determinar o tamanho do box-orange, veja se resolve,

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94736/discussion-between-lucas-antonio-and-guilherme-rigotti).